# How to add images inside the table in beamer

Tags: tables, beamer, floats, themes

I need to insert the images in the table in **Beamer** as shown below

[image]

The shown figure should be one frame in beamer and table must have the boarder

I am  using "Torino" theme in my beamer

can any body tell the beamer code for this.....

thanks in advance.....

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your question. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and think about suitable solutions when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this may be a start though it needs tidying:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{tabular}{|*{4}{c|}} \hline
      & & & \\\hline
      \multirow{3}*{\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-golden-upright}} &   \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a} & \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a} & \hspace*{.205\textwidth}\\\cline{2-3}
      & \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a} & \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a} & \\\cline{2-3}
      & \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a} & \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a} & \\\hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Images in tabular]

## EDIT

To put an image in the final column, as requested in the comments, you can do something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{tabular}{|*{4}{c|}} \hline
      & & & \\\hline
      \multirow{3}*{\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-golden-upright}} &   \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a} & \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a} & \multirow{3}*{\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-golden-upright}}\\\cline{2-3}
      & \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a} & \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a} & \\\cline{2-3}
      & \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a} & \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a} & \\\hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: More images]

Comment: the code is working... thank u so much....but now i need to include an extra image in the 4th column. i m tried with \hspace{\fill}. bit its not working. Am i doing the correct code ? please tell me the correct code for this.....

Comment: @RincyRaphael Just use `\includegraphics...` or if it should span multiple rows, copy the code from the first column and change the filename appropriately. Just replace the `\hspace...` bit. I don't understand what you were trying to do with `\hspace{\fill}`. If you want an image there, include the image.

Comment: i updated the code as you told. But the image is coming in the bottom of the table. How can i arrange it in the center of the column.....

Comment: @RincyRaphael See my edit. Is that what you mean?

Comment: i got the same result. but i need to keep that image in the center of 4th column. now it is coming in the bottom of the table. my image size is same as the "example-a" image.

Comment: @RincyRaphael Use the `fixup` argument to `\multirow`. See the documentation for details. Basically, `\multirow{3}*[fixup length]{content}` where a positive `fixup length` will raise the content. `multirow` tries to centre the contents vertically but doesn't always manage it.